# how do I paste an icon to the terminal

Tags: linux, mac, zsh, iterm2

I'm using `iterm2` on `mac`. I'm using the `oh-my-zsh` and want to add my custom icons like these

[image]

[image]

I wondering if there is a list of all available icons and if mine is not there, how do I add it. I want to add the [git](https://git-scm.com/images/logos/downloads/Git-Icon-1788C.png) icon

Answer (score 0):

These aren't icons, these are characters in fonts, either the ["emoji" characters recently added to Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks), or characters from the "[Private Use Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)" (and the fonts that support them).

I don't think the Git logo is part of them.

Comment: Do you know of an easy way to add a character to a font or to Private Use Areas? considering I have a png file